# How to stop bot from randomly crashing on error EMBED_FIELD_VALUE?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have built a bot that logs messages and used commands in two different channels in an another server. Sometimes it crashes randomly to error "EMBED_FIELD_VALUE" (the bot sends the logs in embeds), and I can't figure out why. I cannot link the error to any specific command. Here is the logging script (copied for each command, it is poorly coded at this point):

```js
        let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('809789122407301229'),
        channel; 
        if (guild) {
        channel = guild.channels.cache.get('838366015951732736');
        const commandEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#00bbff')
        .setTitle('Command Used')
        .addFields(
            {name: 'Username', value: message.author.username},
            {name: 'ID', value: message.author.id},
            {name: 'Command Used', value: message.content},
            {name: 'Channel', value: message.channel.name},
            {name: 'Guild', value: message.guild.name})
        .setFooter('Logs')
        channel.send(commandEmbed);
```

I have thought that DMs can crash the bot, because they are not from a guild, but no one sends DMs to this bot, I am quite certain (but if you have any suggestions on how to fix this also I would like that :D).

Full error:

```
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post the full error heading

Comment: Done, added heading.

Comment: Perhaps since it randomly crashes, you might want to add a data validation before sending the embed to make sure that one of your MessageEmbedField values aren't empty !

Comment: And also, is it your intention to put a "," at the end ? ```{name: 'Guild', value: message.guild.name},)```

Comment: It was not my intention, and the problem has been fixed in the live version. Could you perhaps show me how to fix my problem (by adding the data validation)?